# how to import hippo project into intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, import, hippocms

I am following this tutorial:

https://www.onehippo.org/trails/deep-dive/hello-world.html

I have created and built the project.

When trying to run step 3 I am running into the problem of importing the project into intellij. So far only the project on the site folder is recognized. Does anybody know how to import this kind of project into intellij?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the problem, opening pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA for Import should be enough.

Comment: hippo projects come with 4 modules/subprojects. I was not seeing them on intellij. Turns out I had to activate an option that says always import maven recursively or something like that. A colleague helped me yesterday but I have already forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in place of importing simply open it with intellij, and from maven perspective/view run 'reimport all maven projects'